# Center align text decoration along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, text-decorations, rounded-corners

I am trying to duplicate the node highlighted in green but along a curved path. It mostly works, but when I attempt to apply the `text align=center`  effect to the `decoration`, I get

> Dimension too large.

I get pretty good results if I set `\def\Radius{2.8cm}`.
But, if I set `\def\Radius{2.6cm}`, then I get the same error as above. This I suspect is due to the fact that the text can no longer fit along the given path.

To avoid this problem in the future, if I can get the `text align=center` to work, I can provide a `\path` which is more than sufficient to place the text and draw the `\node` separately.

[image]

As per AndreC's comment, commenting out the `fill=yellow` and `rounded corners=2pt`:

```
\draw [draw=red, 
    postaction={
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|+\tiny\scshape|\MyText},
            raise=0.5ex,
            text align=center,% <---- Uncommented
        },
        decorate,
    },
    %% No error with these commented, but results are wack!!
    %fill=yellow,
    %rounded corners=2pt,
    ]
```

no longer results in an error. However, with this I get the following:

[image]

### Notes:

- The MWE as is produces the image shown above as the `text align=center` is commented out. To get the railing case, that needs to be uncommented.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\MyText}{ABCDEF}

\tikzset{My Node Style/.style={
        fill=green, 
        draw=red, 
        inner sep=2pt,
        rounded corners=2pt,
        font=\tiny,
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        
    \node [My Node Style] at (0,2.5) {\textsc{\MyText}};
    
    \def\Radius{3.0cm}
    \def\StartAngle{100}
    \def\EndAngle{80}
    \def\NodeThickness{1.6ex}
    
    \draw [draw=red, 
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text={|+\tiny\scshape|\MyText},
                raise=0.5ex,
                %text align=center,% <---- ????? Dimension too big ?????
            },
            decorate,
        },
        fill=yellow,
        rounded corners=2pt,
        ] 
        
        ([shift={(\StartAngle:\Radius)}]0,0) 
            arc [start angle=\StartAngle, end angle=\EndAngle, radius=\Radius]
            -- ++(\EndAngle:\NodeThickness)
            arc [start angle=\EndAngle, end angle=\StartAngle, radius=\Radius+\NodeThickness]
            -- cycle
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you comment on the two lines `fill=yellow` and `rounded corners=2pt`, there are no more errors.

Comment: You could just measure the width of the text and then adjust `\StartAngle` and `\EndAngle` to be such that the text is centered. (Of course, this will make the node smaller.)

Comment: There is no error with `text align=left`, but there is one with `text align=right`, would that be a bug with these key?

Comment: @AndréC: Yes, no error, but not quite the results I want. See updated question.

Comment: @marmot: Yep, that was the comment regarding using `\def\Radius{2.8cm}`. However, if the text changes in the future it'll take time for me to figure out what is going on, so would prefer a more robust solution.

Comment: Yes, I had seen, wouldn't that be an incompatibility between `rounded corners` and `text align` keys?

Comment: Sure, but you could do something like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\MyText")}` to determine the right angle for a given radius, or the right radius for a given angle. What I want so say is that you could just make this part of your macro.

Comment: @marmot: Yep, that is a great_ workaround_ and will use that if an actual solution is not found.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, it is definitely only a workaround. If I had an answer, I would have posted it. ;-) (I also tried to switch off the rounded corners for the decorations, but that did not help. My experience is that if there is a `dimension too large` error, there is not much you can do in the sense that you cannot simply switch it off. I've seen a post by Alain Matthes where fp or fpu was used, but I cannot find it any more.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your path starts from the bottom left corner, so when you say `text align=center` you try to center near to the top right corner. But this is not what you want. You want to decorate and center your text only along the bottom (or the top) arc.

So it would be nice if we could make a partial decorate `\path ...decorate{...} ...;` in an post-action, but we can't.

I can imagine two solutions.

**First solution:** start drawing your "node" from the middle top arc, in this may the center of the path will be in the middle of the bottom arc.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt, convert={density=2100}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\MyText}{ABCDEF}

\tikzstyle{My Node Style}=[
  fill=green,
  draw=red,
  inner sep=2pt,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  font=\tiny,
]
\def\Radius{3.0cm}
\def\NodeThickness{1.6ex}
\def\DeltaAngle{10}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[My Node Style] at (0,2.5) {\textsc{\MyText}};
    \draw [draw=red,
      postaction={
        decoration={
          text along path,
          text={|+\tiny\scshape|\MyText},
          raise=\NodeThickness/2-0.4ex,
          text align=center,
        },
        decorate,
      },
      fill=yellow,
      rounded corners=2pt,
    ]
      (90:\Radius+\NodeThickness)
      arc [start angle=90, end angle=90+\DeltaAngle, radius=\Radius+\NodeThickness]
      -- ++(90+\DeltaAngle:-\NodeThickness)
      arc [start angle=90+\DeltaAngle, end angle=90-\DeltaAngle, radius=\Radius]
      -- ++(90-\DeltaAngle:\NodeThickness)
      arc [start angle=90-\DeltaAngle, end angle=90, radius=\Radius+\NodeThickness]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second solution:** You can first draw your "node" and then decorate an arc that goes through the middle of the "node".

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt, convert={density=2100}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\MyText}{ABCDEF}

\tikzstyle{My Node Style}=[
  fill=green,
  draw=red,
  inner sep=2pt,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  font=\tiny,
]
\def\Radius{3.0cm}
\def\NodeThickness{1.6ex}
\def\DeltaAngle{10}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[My Node Style] at (0,2.5) {\textsc{\MyText}};
    \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow,rounded corners=2pt,
    ]
      (90+\DeltaAngle:\Radius)
      arc [start angle=90+\DeltaAngle, end angle=90-\DeltaAngle, radius=\Radius]
      -- ++(90-\DeltaAngle:\NodeThickness)
      arc [start angle=90-\DeltaAngle, end angle=90+\DeltaAngle, radius=\Radius+\NodeThickness]
      -- cycle
    ;
    \path[decorate, decoration={
          text along path,
          text={|+\tiny\scshape|\MyText},
          raise=-0.4ex,
          text align=center
        }
    ]
      (90+\DeltaAngle:\Radius+\NodeThickness/2)
      arc [start angle=90+\DeltaAngle, end angle=90-\DeltaAngle, radius=\Radius+\NodeThickness/2]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note: In the first solution I removed `cycle` because it doesn't work well with `rounded corners` in this case.*